# Compilation error with template class

Tags: c++, templates

I tried with the below code snippet and got the compilation error as described below

Code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class TYPE1>
struct SDataContainer
{
    SDataContainer(TYPE1 pData)
    {
        m_pData = pData;
    }

    bool operator==(const SDataContainer<TYPE1>& pData)
    {
        return (m_pData == pData.m_pData);
    }

    TYPE1 m_pData;
};
template <class DATATYPE1>
class Comparison
{
    public:
        Comparison (const SDataContainer<DATATYPE1>& pSData)
        {
            m_SData = pSData;
        }
        bool operator==(const Comparison<DATATYPE1>& pData)
        {
            return (m_SData.m_pData == pData.m_SData.m_pData);
        }
        SDataContainer<DATATYPE1> m_SData;
};
int main()
{
    SDataContainer<float> sDCObj1 (10.0);
    SDataContainer<float> sDCObj2 (10.0);
    cout << "Verify the data: " << (sDCObj1 == sDCObj2) << endl;
    Comparison<float> sCObj1 (sDCObj1);
    Comparison<float> sCObj2 (sDCObj2);
    cout << "Verify the data: " << (sCObj1 == sCObj2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compialtion error:

template.cpp: In constructor âComparison::Comparison(const SDataContainer&) [with DATATYPE1 = float]â:
template.cpp:45:38:   instantiated from here
template.cpp:26:9: error: no matching function for call to âSDataContainer::SDataContainer()â
template.cpp:26:9: note: candidates are:
template.cpp:8:5: note: SDataContainer::SDataContainer(TYPE1) [with TYPE1 = float]
template.cpp:8:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
template.cpp:6:8: note: SDataContainer::SDataContainer(const SDataContainer&)
template.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provide

I could not get the reason for the compilation error.

Can somebody help me in this issue?

Comment: There is only one constructor for your `SDataContainer<DATATYPE1> m_SData` member to fire, `SDataContainer(TYPE1 pData)`, and it *isn't* default. The error message seems on-point with what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is

```
    Comparison (const SDataContainer<DATATYPE1>& pSData)
      // <<< here
    {
        m_SData = pSData;
    }
```

Because you don't supply an initializer list, one is implied for you, as if you wrote:

```
    Comparison (const SDataContainer<DATATYPE1>& pSData)
    : m_SData()
    {
        m_SData = pSData;
    }
```

which wants to invoke the default constructor for SDataContainer.

The solution is to change your code like this:

```
    Comparison (const SDataContainer<DATATYPE1>& pSData)
    : m_SData(pSData)
    {
    }
```

or to add a default constructor to SDataContainer.

working demo: http://ideone.com/Z0ycCj